# SSIS - How to create staging table in Ole db destination on the fly

Tags: ssis

I am new to SSIS space while developing incremental data load SSIS package I am trying to load data from ole db destination to database. however I can't find a way to create destination table dynamically?

[This](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AhHN5oUCHaJmnH3IM1MwLBN9TngH) is my package I am using project level parameter to input Source conn string(pSourceConnectionString) destination conn string (pDestiConnectionString)
source table (pSourceTable) destination table (pDestiTable).

[Similar problem](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27669986/SSIS-Creating-Destination-Table-Dynamically-From-Source-Table.html)

Comment: You cannot create a table on the fly as the NEW button reads the metadata to create table.The only way is to define it in EXECUTE SQL TASK by chekcing whether the object exists already or not.If not exists ,then create the table.

Comment: Also,technically your solution will not work as the SOURCE always needs the DESTINATION to be mapped.Hence,if you're planning to create the table after fetching the data from SOURCE ,it wont workout really.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a script component as your destination.   The script would start with a command that creates the table if it doesn't exist, and then would insert the incoming rows to it.

There is no way to create an OLEDB Destination to a table that doesn't yet exist.  However,  you could also look into BiML which lets you dynamically create packages based on meta data.

Comment: I don't have any code for this handy.  If you start coding and encounter an error, come back and post it as a new question.